# to avoid nulls how can one formulate a better logic to pass through api results to objects in my project

Tags: c#, null, argumentnullexception

here is a small part of the code if anyone has ideas feel free to hoit me up!

```
public decimal getBook(string pair, decimal amount, string type, string operation, bool division = true)
{
    try
    {   
        //book is null                    
        BinanceOrderBook book = null;

        foreach (var item in Program.array)
            if ((item as Program.ClassDetailOrder).symbol == pair.ToLower())
            {
                book = (item as Program.ClassDetailOrder).book; break;
            }

        // 'lst' is also null nut lst depends on book to not be null. lst is a list but created on the results of the ifs below  (ask and bid are api calls )

        List<BinanceOrderBookEntry> lst = null;
        if (type == "asks")
            lst = book.Asks;
        if (type == "bids")
            lst = book.Bids;

        decimal[] arrayValue = new decimal[2];
        arrayValue[0] = arrayValue[1] = 0;
        decimal orderPrice = 0;
        decimal orderAmount = 0;
        decimal totalCost = 0;
        decimal totalAmount = 0;
        decimal remaining = amount;
        decimal cost = 0;

        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            orderPrice = item.Price;
            orderAmount = item.Quantity;
            cost = orderPrice * orderAmount;
            if (cost < remaining)
            {
                remaining -= cost;
                totalCost += cost;
                totalAmount += orderAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                //finished
                remaining -= amount;
                totalCost += amount * orderPrice;
                totalAmount += amount;
                if (division)
                {
                    arrayValue[0] = Math.Round(amount / (totalCost / totalAmount), 8);
                    arrayValue[1] = Math.Round(amount / orderPrice, 8);
                }
                else
                {
                    arrayValue[0] = Math.Round((totalCost / totalAmount) * amount, 8);
                    arrayValue[1] = Math.Round(orderPrice * amount, 8);
                }
                return arrayValue[0];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your application architecture, adding a few null-checks may solve your issue.

Your **models**:

```
public class ClassDetailOrder
{
    public BinanceOrderBook Book { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}

public class BinanceOrderBook
{
    public List<BinanceOrderBookEntry> Asks { get; set; }
    public List<BinanceOrderBookEntry> Bids { get; set; }
}

public class BinanceOrderBookEntry
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Your **array** of `ClassDetailOrder` with some values (exampled):

```
private readonly ClassDetailOrder[] array = new ClassDetailOrder[]
{
    // Item 0
    null, 
    // Item 1
    new ClassDetailOrder
    {
        Book = new BinanceOrderBook
        {
            Asks = new List<BinanceOrderBookEntry>()
            {
                new BinanceOrderBookEntry { Price = 50, Quantity = 5 }
            }
        },
        Symbol = "book1"
    },
    // Item 2
    new ClassDetailOrder
    {
        Book = new BinanceOrderBook
        {
            Bids = new List<BinanceOrderBookEntry>()
            {
                new BinanceOrderBookEntry { Price = 100, Quantity = 10 }
            }
        },
        Symbol = "book2"
    },
};
```

Calling `GetBook` method with different parameters:

```
private void GetSomeBooks()
{
    GetBook("Book0", 1, "asks", "");
    GetBook(null, 2, "bids", "");
    GetBook("Book2", 3, "asks", "");
    GetBook("Book1", 4, null, "");
}
```

And your `GetBook` method (with *few* my additions, changes and comments):

```
public decimal GetBook(string pair, decimal amount, string type, string operation, bool division = true)
{
    // Default value
    var result = -1.0M;

    try
    {
        if (array is null)
        {
            // Handle in some way that "Array of ClassDetailOrders was null."
            return result;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pair))
        {
            // Handle in some way that "Pair value must be specified."
            return result;
        }
 
        // Getting first Book from not-null(!) ClassDetailOrder,
        // which Symbol matches to provided "pair" value
        var book = array.FirstOrDefault(item => item?.Symbol == pair.ToLower())?.Book;

        // Book will be null if:
        // - all ClassDetailOrders in array was null
        // - no ClassDetailOrder with some Symbol that match to pair.ToLower() was found
        // - Book property of founded ClassDetailOrder was null by itself


        // Checking Book is null or not and go out from method if null
        if (book is null)
        {
            // Handle in some way that "Specified Book wasn't found."
            return result;
        }

        // If Book wasn't null, initializing List
        var lst = (List<BinanceOrderBookEntry>)null;
 
        // Provided "type" value also may be null or empty
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
        {
            // Handle in some way that "Book Type must be specified."
            return result;
        }
          
        switch (type)
        {
            case "asks":
                lst = book.Asks;
                break;
            case "bids":
                lst = book.Bids;
                break;
        }

        // Same null-check as for Book above, but for List now
        if (lst is null)
        {
            // Handle in some way that "Book items of provided Type was null.";
            return result;
        }

        decimal[] arrayValue = new decimal[2] { 0M, 0M };
        decimal orderPrice = 0, orderAmount = 0, totalCost = 0, totalAmount = 0, cost = 0;
        decimal remaining = amount;

        foreach (var item in lst)
        {
            // Same null-check as for Book and List above
            if (item is null)
            {
                // Handle in some way that item was null, e.g.:
                continue;
                // or 
                return result;
            }

            orderPrice = item.Price;
            orderAmount = item.Quantity;
            cost = orderPrice * orderAmount;

            remaining = cost < remaining ? remaining - cost : remaining - amount;    
            totalCost = cost < remaining ? totalCost + cost : amount * orderPrice;    
            totalAmount = cost < remaining ? totalAmount + orderAmount : totalAmount + amount;

            // Reversed if because of ternary replacements
            if (cost >= remaining)
            {
                arrayValue[0] = division
                                ? Math.Round(amount / (totalCost / totalAmount), 8)
                                : Math.Round(totalCost / totalAmount * amount, 8);

                arrayValue[1] = division
                                ? Math.Round(amount / orderPrice, 8)
                                : Math.Round(orderPrice * amount, 8);

                result = arrayValue[0];
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The main idea, that you should understand, is **to check every nullable object for possible null value** where you can. In this example we possibly may have **8** objects, which could be `null` and may cause `NullReferenceException`. And you can handle them all:

1. For `array` of `ClassDetailOrder` (to be able search for `ClassDetailOrder` items in it);
2. For provided `pair` value (to avoid null exception when lowercasing with `ToLower()`);
3. For each `ClassDetailOrder` (to avoid null exceptions while searching for `Book`);
4. For `ClassDetailOrder` at result (if no one was found by `FirstOrDefault` method);
5. For `Book` (to be sure that we can access it's `Asks`/`Bids` lists);
6. For provided `type` value (to be sure be can take proper `List` (Asks or Bids or any other you will have));
7. For `List` (to be sure, that `List` at least empty, but not null);
8. For `BinanceOrderBookEntry` item in `foreach` loop over `List` (to be sure we can access its `Price` and `Quantity` properties).

You can handle null-checks in a way you wish or return value you wish or reverse `if`s to `is not null` (`!= null`) way.

You can tests different values to try cover all null-checks and test them.